# Find and replace a string inside an image path

Tags: xslt

I have a rss xml file that looks like below with the  tag looping many times. I would like to replace the letter 's' with 'm' in the url inside the  tag, So http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3802/9593294742_a38fca47c7_s.jpg becomes http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3802/9593294742_a38fca47c7_m.jpg

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/creativeCommonsRssModule.html" xmlns:flickr="urn:flickr:user" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>CCGalleria Pool</title>
        <link>http://www.flickr.com/groups/ccgalleria/pool/</link>
        <item>
        <title>Hampton Court Palace Gardens</title>
        <link>http://www.flickr.com/photos/dksesh/9593294742/in/pool-1540822@N20</link>
        <description>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.flickr.com/people/dksesh/">dksesh</a>
            has added a photo to the pool:</p>
            <p>
            <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/dksesh/9593294742/" title="Hampton Court Palace Gardens">
          <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3802/9593294742_a38fca47c7_m.jpg" width="240" height="107" alt="Hampton Court Palace Gardens"/>
            </a>
            </p>
    </description>
    <pubDate>Sun, 25 Aug 2013 10:33:09 -0700</pubDate>
    <dc:date.Taken>2013-08-10T16:49:05-08:00</dc:date.Taken>
    <author flickr:profile="http://www.flickr.com/people/dksesh/">nobody@flickr.com (dksesh)</author>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">tag:flickr.com,2004:/grouppool/1540822@N20/photo/9593294742</guid>
    <media:content url="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3802/9593294742_a38fca47c7_b.jpg" type="image/jpeg" height="456" width="1024"/>
    <media:title>Hampton Court Palace Gardens</media:title>
    <media:thumbnail url="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3802/9593294742_a38fca47c7_s.jpg" HEIGHT="75" WIDTH="75"/>
    <media:credit ROLE="photographer">dksesh</media:credit>
    <creativeCommons:license>http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/deed.en_GB</creativeCommons:license>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I have a code something like below, but didn't work. Can someone help? Thanks very much. Newly changed code below.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
             xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
  <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
      <xsl:variable name="newurl" select="replace(media:thumbnail/@url,'_s.jpg','_m.jpg')"/>
      <img src="{$newurl}" style="margin:5px 5px" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 is pretty poor at string handling operations such as this. `translate` will indiscriminately affect all matches within the string, whereas you are interested only in the last one, seemingly. Traditional replacement is normally done in XSLT with a mix of `substring-before` and `substring-after`, to split at a point and then re-glue the pieces. Do a search for that - I would have thought there were a lot of questions on SO re: XSLT string replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stylesheet sample showns the version as "2.0" which is good, because there is a [replace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) function you can use in XSLT 2.0 that will probably do the trick here

```
<xsl:variable name="newurl" select="replace(media:thumbnail/@url,'_s.jpg','_m.jpg')"/>
<img src="{$newurl}" style="margin:5px 5px" />
```

Note that the second argument of the replace function can actually be a regular expression, if you wanted more control over what 's' needed to be replaced.

As an aside, do note the correct use of Attribute Value Templates here, signified by the curly braces `{ }`. You use them in outputting the **src** attribute of the **img** element, but not within the translate/replace function.

Here is the full XSLT in this case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
             xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">

<xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
      <xsl:variable name="newurl" select="replace(media:thumbnail/@url,'_s.jpg','_m.jpg')"/>
      <img src="{$newurl}" style="margin:5px 5px" />
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, when I tried the code below it says 'an error occurred applying the XSL transform'.

Comment: <?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
             xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
  <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
      <xsl:variable name="newurl" select="replace(media:thumbnail/@url,'_s.jpg','_m.jpg')"/>
      <img src="{$newurl}" style="margin:5px 5px" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I've added a full (working) XSLT sample to my answer, which should hopefully help. The code you show in your comment has spurious semi-colons in, and an incorrecr namespace for xsl.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply again. I put the code below, but unfortunately it is still getting the same error.

Comment: <?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
             xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">

<xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
      <xsl:variable name="newurl" select="replace(media:thumbnail/@url,'_s.jpg','_m.jpg')"/>
      <img src="{$newurl}" style="margin:5px 5px" />
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: The semi colon is added in by the system automatically, please look at the code above. Thanks.

Comment: I am confused, because the XSLT in your question has no semi-colons, and also the namespace for xmlns:xsl is correct in your question. I tested my XSLT at http://xslttest.appspot.com/ and it worked fine too! If something is adding semi-colons to youe XSLT then I think you whole new issue, I am afraid!

Comment: Hi Tim. Yes, it does work on xslttest.appspot.com I am not quite sure why as well. I will take a look with my friend later and see if there's something else wrong. Thanks for your help for now and I will let you know how it goes.